# Neo4j Browser equivalent for SQL Server Graph DB?

Tags: sql-server, graph, neo4j

SQL Server's new graph capabilities are convenient for a data warehouse project I have. I really like the Neo4j Browser when your graph db is neo: is there something similar that I could use to talk to my SQL Server graph data?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[This article on a SQL Server recommendation system](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlcat/2017/04/21/build-a-recommendation-system-with-the-support-for-graph-data-in-sql-server-2017-and-azure-sql-db/) contains, at the bottom, an example of how to create a graph visualization using the open source package [igraph](http://igraph.org/r/).

Comment: Thank @cybersam. I'm a huge R fan but I don't want to write code to do this.  I'm looking for an interactive UI that I can submit queries to, pan, zoom, hover on nodes, style with configuration, etc..  Basically, the neo4J browser experience!